# Simple MySQL INSERT query very slow

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04

I think I'm having an issue with my MySQL server or the Query I'm using. I'm not sure which.

Server is VM Ubuntu12.4 4 cores/16gb Ram
MySQL 5.5.24 x86

My query:

```
INSERT INTO `NEWTEXT`.`Order_LineDetails`

( OrderLineItem_ID, Customer_ID, Order_ID, ProductName )
SELECT
'Order_Details'.'OrderDetailID',
'Orders'.'CustomerID',
'Order_Details'.'OrderID',
'prods'.'ProductName'

FROM Order_Details 
JOIN Orders ON Orders.OrderID = Order_Details.OrderID
JOIN Products prods ON prods.ProductID = Order_Details.ProductID
WHERE Orders.OrderID = 500000
```

I'm not really sure where to start looking for the problem. The above query takes 9+ seconds to complete. The Order_Details table contains 1,800,000+ records in it.

The thing that is bugging me on this is that when I run a select query it also goes slow.  BUT, I have another server that's running win2k MsSql and its almost instant with the same SELECT query.

I'm hoping someone could point me in the right direction here.

### EDIT

Well, sorry for the troubles and thanks for your help.

I found that the problem was that after I finished the import I skipped the step where I would normally assign the new tables a `PrimaryKey`. I know, :( dumb.

Anyway! Don't forget to assign your `Primary Keys`!

Comment: Please show your table structures so we can see what indexes you have defined.

Comment: Have you looked at the output of EXPLAIN for the select query?

Comment: Your insert has 3 columns, but your select has 4

Comment: As @MikeBrant says, show your table structure. You can use http://sqlfiddle.com/ to share it.

Comment: @Nathan That should actually not have a performance impact, though it would seem odd to include the prods table in the select query at all if it is not going to ultimately be inserted.

Comment: I do have 4 columns in the insert. Sorry, I missed it on the post.

Comment: Hint - the performance has very little to do with "Server is VM Ubuntu12.4 4 cores/16gb Ram MySQL 5.5.24 x86"

Comment: Feeling a little dumb right now. Let me build the indexes for these and get back to you guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Back to the start:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-primary-keys.html